# How to check if constant is defined, inside function - php

Tags: php, function, variables, constants

I am trying to make a small PHP function which can check if a constant is defined, and if so, echo it, and if not, echo space or nothing.

Right now, the `if(defined()` part is not working, because the constant is being transferred to a variable inside the function.

```
function getConstant($constant) {  
  if(defined($constant)) {
    echo constant($constant);
  } else {
    echo '';
  }
}
```

The `echo constant($constant)` part is working fine, but I cannot check if the constant is actually defined because it is a variable now.

I cannot seem to find a solution for it

Comment: What do you mean the constant is transferred to a variable? You mean the constant's name?

Comment: All works fine https://3v4l.org/a8Rgh

Comment: `$constant` must be a __string__ with constant's name.

Comment: code is working fine:- https://eval.in/708124

Comment: If $constant is a string which you expect will have the constant literal, code is ok. May be having namespacnig issues? Are you inside a class?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static function isConstants($constant) {
    $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    $allConstants = $oClass->getConstants();
    if (isset($allConstants[$constant])) {
       echo $allConstants[$constant];
    } else {
       echo '';
    }
}
```